# Hyperledger-composer Access Control Rules and Transactions

Tags: transactions, hyperledger-composer, access-control

My question is on access control rules and transactions in hyperledger-composer.

In the case of named queries, the sender of the query will only get to see those results, for which he has READ ACCESS.

Is this the same with transactions or will transactions be blocked as soon as the transaction sender does not have READ ACCESS to any one element contained in the overall pool?

Example:

Overall pool consists of all "Clients".

Participant XY (who doesn't have READ access to some of the Clients)sends transaction to Participant Registry containing all Clients, using "getAll()".

Will the transaction be blocked or will Participant XY receive those clients for whom he/she has READ ACCESS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Participant XY, in your scenario, will only be able to read those Clients you've ALLOWed XY to access by ACL rules (the same, in principle, as what you see from query results). The transaction does not 'block' as a result ; the rules simply apply access control over the resources/operations within a business network.